# Pandas DataFrame: how to calculate how many times certain rows had the same column values?

Tags: python, pandas

[image]

Given above dataset, *I have to calculate how many times `product_no` 813 and 811 have the same `order_id`*. For example, in the first three rows, all have the same `order_id` and 813 and 811 have the same order_id only once(do not consider duplicates of 811).

Actually, I have to do it for every product and produce some matrix or data structure which looks like this:

```
{'813': {
   'count': 33,      # total 33 times present in the dataset
   'together': {
   '811': 9,         # 9 times it has the same order_id as 811
   '812': 6,
   '832': 1,
   '830': 1,
   '831': 1,
   '1867': 1,
   '3415': 1,
   '3029': 1,
   '2856': 1,
   '3533': 1,
   '3061': 1,
   '3687': 1,
   '939': 1,
   '311': 1,
   '4376': 1,
   '4377': 1,
   '2259': 1,
   '3965': 1,
   '1559': 1,
   '1246': 1,
   '3014': 1,
   '3730': 1,
   '5348': 1,
   '357': 1,
   '5079': 1,
   '6052': 1
   },
 ...               # for other products
```

My following pure python brute force approach:

```
for rows in temp_df.groupby('order_id'):    # temp_df is the dataset
  # print(type(rows[1]))

  prods = set(list(map(int, list(rows[1]['product_no']))))   # get current set of products which has the same order_id
  for prod in prods:
    prod = str(prod)
    res[str(prod)]['count'] += 1
    for each in prods:
      each = str(each)
      if each != prod:
        if each in res[prod]['together']:
          res[prod]['together'][each] += 1
        else:
          res[prod]['together'][each] = 1
    res[prod]['together'] = dict(sorted(res[prod]['together'].items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True))
```

It would be great if i can get matrix instead of dictionary but dictionary is also alright.

Comment: You need to provide data in a format that is not a picture.

Comment: I can't share the dataset as it is quite sensitive

Answer (score 0):

You could use groupby :

```
df_group=groupby(by="product_no")
```

And

```
df_group.ngroups
```

will give you the total count

You can iter over every grouped dataframe (using groups attribute for instance) to perform a new groupby(by="order_id").

Make a list
`L=[product_no ,{order_id: len(df)}]`

Iter over it the same way you did :

```
results={}  
for i,el in enumerate(L):
        results[el[0]]={}
        for el2 in L[i:]:
            common_id=el[1].keys() & el2[1].keys()
            results[el[0]][el2[0]]=len(common_id)
```

I think you may even do both groupby at once, I am typing on my phone so I cannot test anything and I have probably done many mistakes, but you get the idea.

Edit : actually i was considering duplicates at first, this can be simplify even more if you are just looking for the number of common id. You then do not need the groupby on id but just df["order_id"].unique() (or consider dropping duplicates at the very beginning which is even simpler)